# How do I properly use dependency injection to include asp.net core identity UserManager on a Blazor component?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor, identity

How do I properly use dependency injection to include asp.net core identity UserManager on a Blazor component?

I scaffolded Identity into the project, created a custom field, and edited the Identity pages for displaying and editing this field during registration and profile pages.

Being that those pages are mainly for the logged in user, I need to build a page for an admin to view and edit users.

I created a Blazor page and copied from "Index.cshtml.cs" this code which appears all over the internet as well:

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

    public IndexModel(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
```

I used the guide here: [Micosoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#specify-a-base-class), to create a Razor Component to specify a base class for the component. Being that it is a server side Blazor app, I am thinking that this should be fine, but it is not.

My class code is:

```
namespace UsersComponent
{
public class UsersBase : ComponentBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public UsersBase(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

I am getting this error on the dependency injection of:

```
    public UsersBase(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

The error is this:

```
CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'userManager' of 'UsersBase.UsersBase(UserManager<ApplicationUser>)'
```

Can anyone point me towards alleviating this error? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using something like the following in `Program.cs` :
`builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>...`

For injection in razor components your need to use the `[Inject]` attribute on a property or `@inject ...` in the razor markup area.

`UsersBase.cs`

```
public class UsersBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject] 
    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser>? UserManager { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I remember seeing that a couple days ago when I was researching something else. Thank you very much. I knew it was something simple like that!

Comment: @JoelMason You should click the tick to accept the answer to close it.